# I want to switch off the internet for my LAN connection but i want my network drives to work?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

Is there any possibility that i can turn off my internet from my LAN connection but i want my central network drives to work? My systems are running on Win XP and Win 7. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to disconnect from the internet but continue on using the local network (LAN)? Do you control the router and can disable the internet connection in it?

Comment: no i dont control the router! I just want to block the internet for some requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block the internet, leaving the LAN still connected you may:

- Disable IPv4/6 in the computer

  These protocols are used for the internet (or local Web servers inside the LAN)
  and can be temporarily disabled in:
  *Network and Sharing Centre > Change adapter settings*.
  Right-click the adapter, select *Properties*, uncheck both
  "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP4)" and
  "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP6)", and click OK.
- Add a false proxy

  This will cause all internet connections to fail. This is done in
  *Internet Properties > Connections > LAN settings*.
  Uncheck "Automatically detect settings" and check "Use proxy server" and define
  a proxy server that doesn't exist. This will time out the Web browser.
- Block outgoing ports 80 and 443 in the firewall

  This will block browser connections for HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Wouldn't this not address other Internet ports, such as SSH (22), FTP, etc.? Seems like a very crude solution w/o control of the upstream network hardware

Comment: @InterLinked: Improvements are always possible, but the poster indicated that he cannot control the router.

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't work. It blocks the internet but now I don't have access to the network drives.

Comment: You don't need to do all of the above methods, just the one that will suit your situation.

Comment: The first one works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This sounds dangerous.  To clarify: This shouldn't be dangerous for a person who knows what they are doing.  But after reading the question, I wonder if it is a good idea.

Well, there are two ways this can commonly be done, assuming your "network drives" are part of your LAN.  One option is to unplug power from a device needed to reach the Internet, such as a "cable modem", "DSL modem", or "firewall".  (Or, as harrymc indicated, a router.)

Another approach may be to clear out the "Default Gateway" settings for the network adapter.  The "Default Gateway" is typically a router (side note: a firewall acts as a router, and so do many "modem" devices) that is used to forward traffic to most locations on the planet (so, the Internet).  So, if you make sure the "Default Gateway" settings (under Control Panel, Network...) are not automatic, and are blank, that may do the trick.  You could still communicate with your local subnet (typically meaning: your LAN).

(Still, that doesn't guarantee you won't communicate to the Internet somehow less directly.  If an attacker used to Internet to take over another device on your LAN, your computer may still communicate with that device on the LAN, so you could still be vulnerable.)

Comment: No, the network drives are part of my LAN connections so I cannot unplug any device. So I dont have any option of switching off the router its more like a central LAN connection from the server (from the organization).